# IntelliJ add Java 11

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to add my installed Java 11 version to the project settings, because of this error (Error:java: invalid source release: 11).

When i go to project structure -> Project settings -> Project there it just shows Java 1.8.
When i try to add "java-11-openjdk-amd64" it fails with the reason "The selected directory points to a JRE, not a JDK.".

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java` application is available in the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The fact that `java` is available in version 11 does not necessarily mean that the Java Development Kit (JDK) is also installed for version 11. However, IntelliJ needs the JDK which includes tools like the compiler `javac`.

In order to use Java 11 in IntelliJ, you need to install the Java 11 JDK.

For example on Ubuntu you can do that by executing:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```